# Elasticsearch/kibana Logs export via raw log format

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kibana, elk

We have elasticsearch, filebeat, kibana at our stateful deployment inside kubernetes cluster. We have nfs server outside of kuberentes cluster as VM from where we've using static provisioning of NFS mounted inside Elasticsearch pods to preserve log.

Is there's any ways by which we can export logs from elasticsearch/ kibana in raw format?

Comment: `logs it received via filebeat and indexed it` is not a "raw log".

Comment: Yeah, that’s what i was asking, is there’s any way by which those indexed logs can be exported as raw logs? 

Thanks

Comment: It was asked [a lot of time ago](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/can-we-export-logs-in-raw-format-from-elasticsearch/49447) with the answer `no`. However maybe something changed. I'd ask them directly on the forum